# Safari Browser z-index or Transform CSS Property Issue - Elements Not Visible / Backgrounded

Tags: safari, rendering, mobile-safari, z-index, visibility

I've got an issue with visibility of HTML elements in Safari (**Mobile and Desktop**) not rendering in the foreground that I've spent at least 8 hours of dedicated troubleshooting on trying to address.

The concept I'm after seems very simple; I'm trying to display a couple of labels (`<p>`'s and `<a>`'s within a `<div>` that is `position:absolute;`.  I'm leveraging a 3rd party Javascript coverflow that is forcing the absolute positioning but I'm willing to make any modifications needed to get this working.

I naturally assumed this was a `z-index` issue that was only effecting Safari but there are no rendering issues in Chrome, IE, Edge, and Firefox including Android mobile devices.

The issue can easily be reproduced on www.bibleanthem.com when looking at the media coverflow from iOS/Safari and likely macOS; for a brief second while it is initially loading, the elements are visible and then the album artwork moves to the foreground.  You can also see a slight hint of the '+1' badge on the corner at the lower edge of the album artwork. **You can even click where the two invisible buttons are and interact with the document (e.g. play song immediately or add to playlist)**.

**What I've Tried**

- Changing (and IIRC dropping entirely) `transform` usage from each Coverflow item (see "Additional Detail" section below for an important note)
- `z-index` changes (including absurdly large values like 10000000000000)
- Changing `position` to fixed, relative, sticky for the parent div
- Changing `position` to fixed, relative, sticky for child elements
- Changing `display` between block and inline-block
- Changing `overflow` on most elements in the hierarchy

**Additional Detail**

- I've seen issues in the past with Safari not playing nicely with `transform`; that could be the issue here and the symptoms are very similar to my past experiences but I haven't been able to fix the issue.  This is where I'd guess the problem actually resides.

**Rendered HTML for each Coverflow item**

```
<div style="position: absolute; display: block; overflow: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; max-width: none; max-height: none; border: none; line-height: 1; background-color: transparent; backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; width: 95px; transform: translate(142px, 119px); opacity: 1;"><p class="largeLabel"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="...not shown" title="Add to Playlist (play next)" class="rel-title-play-next round-button"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i><span class="badge">+1</span></a><a href="javascript:;" onclick="...not shown" title="Play Immediately" class="rel-title-play-now round-button"><i class="fa fa-play play-btn-adjust"></i></a></p><p class="smallLabel"><span class="title-cf-main">Song Title</span><br><span class="title-cf-artist">Artist Title</span><br><span class="title-cf-verse">Acts 17</span></p></div>
```

**How To Reproduce**

- Visit www.bibleanthem.com from desktop or mobile Safari and notice how the album artwork takes foreground positioning over the label/text.

**Desired End State**

- The blue background label, song title, artist title, and verse title should be visible **above** the album artwork in the coverflow (as seen in non-Safari browsers)

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.  I can't tell you how much I'd appreciate addressing this issue!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the z-index on the div instead of the label. If you create a fiddle I'll play around with it a little more.

Comment: thanks so much for offering up you suggestion and your willingness to help solve this!  I was beginning to lose hope!  Let me see if I can get together a fiddle for this, I need to ponder the best way to reproduce just that section.   Sorry for the slow reply and hopefully your offer still stands!

Comment: Appreciate it very much.  I'll be in touch shortly.

Comment: Hi @Swazimodo, I'm still working through other portions of this dev project but this still remains crucial for me.  I haven't forgotten, sorry for the delay!